# Payload --- > Form Data : page: 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

собираю данные с сайта, изпользую заголовки для получения html страницы с товарами:

```
headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/......',
    'User-Agent': ua.random
}
```

данные сохраняются но не все , на сайте идет динамическая подгрузка контента , показывает по 50 товаров, при прокрутке к следующи пятидесяти товарам,  делается еще один ззапрос и в параметрах передается payload / А как мне указать в заголовках такой же payload ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ссылку на сайт скинте

Comment: magnit.ru/promo